# SQL group data based on a column and pivot rows to (unknown) columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a synonyms table into an unknown number of columns (T-SQL). I'm using SQL Server 2017.

I have this table:

| fd_Id | fd_Word | fd_Interpretation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | smile | 1 |
| 2 | grin | 1 |
| 3 | laugh | 1 |
| 4 | see | 2 |
| 5 | detect | 2 |
| 6 | look | 2 |
| 7 | peek | 2 |
| 8 | walk | 3 |
| 9 | stroll | 3 |

`fd_Id` is an identity column and synonyms are grouped by `fd_Interpretation`. While synonyms can have any number of rows (10+), in practice they are around 6 to 8.

This is the desired output:

| Id | Word1 | Word2 | Word3 | Word4 | Wordn... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | grin | laugh | smile |  |  |
| 2 | detect | look | peek | see |  |
| 3 | stroll | walk |  |  |  |

`Id` is a `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK`. Optional if too much trouble.

I looked at other similar PIVOT row questions here but couldn't find one that is close enough.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: so you nned to pivot your data with the dded word dynamic you will find multiple solutions

Comment: Your selected solution does not support _an unknown number of columns_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-up PIVOT in concert `row_number()` with  should do the trick

```
Select *
 From (
        Select ID = fd_Interpretation
              ,Item = concat('Word',row_number() over (partition by fd_Interpretation order by fd_Word) )
              ,Value = fd_Word
         From  YourTable
      ) src
 Pivot ( max( Value ) for Item in ([Word1],[Word2],[Word3],[Word4],[Word5],[Word6],[Word7],[Word8]) ) pvt
```

Comment: John Cappelletti, Beautiful! Thank you!