# SQL group data based on a column and pivot rows to (unknown) columns - all possible combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a synonyms table (all possible combinations) into an unknown number of columns (T-SQL). I'm using SQL Server 2017.

I have this table:

| fd_Id | fd_Word | fd_Interpretation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | smile | 1 |
| 2 | grin | 1 |
| 3 | laugh | 1 |
| 4 | see | 2 |
| 5 | detect | 2 |
| 6 | look | 2 |
| 7 | peek | 2 |
| 8 | walk | 3 |
| 9 | stroll | 3 |

`fd_Id` is an identity column and synonyms are grouped by `fd_Interpretation`. While synonyms can have any number of rows (10+), in practice they are around 6 to 8.

This is the desired output:

| Id | Word1 | Word2 | Word3 | Word4 | Wordn... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | grin | laugh | smile |  |  |
| 2 | laugh | grin | smile |  |  |
| 3 | smile | grin | laugh |  |  |
| 4 | detect | look | peek | see |  |
| 5 | look | detect | peek | see |  |
| 6 | peek | detect | look | see |  |
| 7 | see | detect | look | peek |  |
| 8 | stroll | walk |  |  |  |
| 9 | walk | stroll |  |  |  |

The idea is to get all words listed in the first column and its remaining synonyms on the columns to the right.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your progress since [SQL group data based on a column and pivot rows to (unknown) columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73113036/92546).

Comment: Not a repost. First question was answered. This one is different in that all possible combinations are needed.

Comment: I don't understand the logic: why does row 3 have `smile` twice? And how do you decide the order, is it just each row's value is last and all others are random?

Comment: Fixed. First column order is ASC based on (grouped by) `fd_Interpretation`. The remaining synonyms are ordered ASC (left to right).

Comment: Clearly not a repost and, like your previous question, containing no code. "I have"/"This is the desired output" does not show any effort on your part to solve the problem.

Comment: Solved it (30mins) before your comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
SELECT
     [fd_Id] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pvt.[Keyword] ASC), *
FROM
    (SELECT
        src.[fd_Interpretation],
        [Keyword] = src.[fd_Keyword],       
        [Item] = CONCAT('Synonym', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY src.fd_Keyword ORDER BY src.fd_Keyword)),
        [Value] = src.[fd_Synonym] --fd_Keyword
    FROM
        (
        SELECT MAX(a.fd_Interpretation) AS [fd_Interpretation], MAX(u.fd_Keyword) AS [fd_Keyword], NULL AS [fd_Synonym] 
        FROM dbo.tb_Synonyms a INNER JOIN dbo.tb_UniqueKeywords u ON u.fd_Id = a.fd_Keyword
        GROUP BY a.fd_Interpretation
        HAVING COUNT(fd_Interpretation) = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            a.fd_Interpretation, u.fd_Keyword, u1.fd_Keyword AS [fd_Synonym]
        FROM
            dbo.tb_Synonyms a INNER JOIN dbo.tb_UniqueKeywords u ON u.fd_Id = a.fd_Keyword
        CROSS JOIN
            dbo.tb_Synonyms b INNER JOIN dbo.tb_UniqueKeywords u1 ON u1.fd_Id = b.fd_Keyword
        WHERE
            a.fd_Interpretation = b.fd_Interpretation AND
            a.fd_Keyword <> b.fd_Keyword) src
    ) src1
PIVOT
    (MAX([Value]) FOR [Item] IN ([Synonym1], [Synonym2], [Synonym3], [Synonym4], [Synonym5], [Synonym6], [Synonym7], [Synonym8], [Synonym9], [Synonym10])) pvt;
```

Thanks to @john-cappelletti; used his answer to my other question and extended it to answer this one.

The actual words are on another table `tb_UniqueKeywords` (but that doesn't really change anything), as it functions as the original table in the question, as can be seen here:

```
SELECT
    s.fd_Id,
    u.fd_Keyword,
    s.fd_Interpretation
FROM
    tb_Synonyms s INNER JOIN
    tb_UniqueKeywords u ON s.fd_Keyword = u.fd_Id
```

Output:

```
fd_Id       fd_Keyword                                         fd_Interpretation
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------------
3           2                                                  1
5           Doble                                              1
4           Dos                                                1
6           Mayra                                              2
8           Vecina                                             2
7           5                                                  3
13          Una                                                4
14          Unas                                               4
9           Uno                                                4
10          Unos                                               4
11          Oficina                                            5
12          Oficinas                                           5
```

It also correctly outputs words with no synonyms (as in the case of Keyword `5`) due to the `UNION ALL` table which handles that.

Final output:

```
fd_Id                fd_Interpretation Keyword                                            Synonym1                                           Synonym2                                           Synonym3                                           Synonym4                                           Synonym5                                           Synonym6                                           Synonym7                                           Synonym8                                           Synonym9                                           Synonym10
-------------------- ----------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1                    1                 2                                                  Doble                                              Dos                                                NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
2                    3                 5                                                  NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
3                    1                 Doble                                              2                                                  Dos                                                NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
4                    1                 Dos                                                2                                                  Doble                                              NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
5                    2                 Mayra                                              Vecina                                             NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
6                    5                 Oficina                                            Oficinas                                           NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
7                    5                 Oficinas                                           Oficina                                            NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
8                    4                 Una                                                Unas                                               Uno                                                Unos                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
9                    4                 Unas                                               Una                                                Uno                                                Unos                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
10                   4                 Uno                                                Una                                                Unas                                               Unos                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
11                   4                 Unos                                               Una                                                Unas                                               Uno                                                NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
12                   2                 Vecina                                             Mayra                                              NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using dynamic pivot.

Note: But, I don't still understand, why you want to have all possible combinations of the same. It will lead to more complications and I have not addressed that in this solution.

```sql
CREATE table dbo.meaning (fd_Id int, fd_Word    varchar(50), fd_Interpretation int)

insert into dbo.meaning values
(1,'smile   ',1)
,(2,'grin   ',1)
,(3,'laugh  ',1)
,(4,'see    ',2)
,(5,'detect ',2)
,(6,'look   ',2)
,(7,'peek   ',2)
,(8,'walk   ',3)
,(9,'stroll ',3);

SELECT *,concat('word', cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FD_interpretation order by fd_word) as int)) as word FROM meaning


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + concat('word', cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FD_interpretation order by fd_Word) as int))
            FROM dbo.meaning c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT fd_interpretation,' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select fd_interpretation, fd_word, concat(''word'', cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FD_interpretation order by fd_Word) as int)) as word
                from dbo.meaning
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(fd_word)
                for word in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

| fd_interpretation | word1 | word2 | word3 | word4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | grin | laugh | smile | NULL |
| 2 | detect | look | peek | see |
| 3 | stroll | walk | NULL | NULL |